# Yakindu application cannot run on elementary OS

Tags: release-loki

I am trying to run Yakindu (https://www.itemis.com/en/yakindu/state-machine/) on elementary OS.

But as soon as I start it the GUI starts slowing down until it is not responding anymore/is frozen.

I tried it on 2 different computers running Elementary OS (a desktop and a laptop: different CPU, different GPU) with the same result.

Note 1: Yakindu is based on eclipse and eclipse is running OK on Elementary OS.

Note 2: Yakindu is running OK on an Ubuntu system.

Note 3: When Yakindu is started the Xserver seems to be getting a lot of CPU load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu (and thus eOS) has issues running GTK3 applications (Eclipse uses GTK3, and as a consequence Yakindu probably does too.)

In Eclipse's case, this is solved by adding this to the `eclipse.ini` file

On the line before

`--launcher.appendVmargs`, you add:

```
--launcher.GTK_version

2
```

I would expect a similar file to be part of your Yakindu installation, could you search for it, make the appropiate changes and try to run it again?

Comment: Your are right.

I added the 2 lines on the SCT.ini file and everything seems to work now.

Thanks